# How can I print content inside a string in Python?

Tags: python, api, get, python-requests

I'm testing an API from Rapidapi.com using Python 3.8 and Requests module. This is the code:

```
import requests

url = "https://netflix-unofficial.p.rapidapi.com/api/genres"

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "netflix-unofficial.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': //here goes my private key
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

data = response.text

print(data)
```

The output I obtain is like this:

```
{"data":["Action & Adventure","Anime Features","Children & Family Movies","Classic Movies","Cult Movies","Documentaries","Dramas","Faith & Spirituality","Horror Movies","Independent Movies","International Movies","LGBTQ Movies","Movies","Music & Musicals","Romantic Movies","Sci-Fi & Fantasy","Sports Movies","Stand-Up Comedy","Thrillers"]}
```

But I want have access to every single genre listed and show it like this instead:

```
- Genre 1
- Genre 2
...
- Genre n
```

Comment: So you want to print the text `"- Genre"` followed by a number? What did you do to get this?

Comment: No, I want to output the hyphen ("-") juxtaposing the genre name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string as er below.

```
Gene_Dict = '{"data":["Action & Adventure","Anime Features","Children & Family Movies","Classic Movies","Cult Movies","Documentaries","Dramas","Faith & Spirituality","Horror Movies","Independent Movies","International Movies","LGBTQ Movies","Movies","Music & Musicals","Romantic Movies","Sci-Fi & Fantasy","Sports Movies","Stand-Up Comedy","Thrillers"]}'
Gene_Dict = Gene_Dict.strip()     
Gene_Dict = eval(Gene_Dict)

for ele in Gene_Dict[Gene_Dict.keys()[0]]: print ele
```

Comment: Error: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: Added few line in the code to convert string into dictionary.

Comment: Don't use `eval`, that's very bad practice. The data is JSON, one should use JSON. Also,  `Gene_Dict.keys()[0]` is unnecessary and dangerous, because 1/ the key is well known, it's `'data'` and 2/ if there were more than one key, there's no guarantee that you would get the right one. Also, the output is not formatted as expected.

Comment: You can have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) about why not to use eval.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the genres are stored in the variable data as single elements in an array. You could run a loop for the length of the data variable and then print the individual elements:

```
print(data[i])
```

Comment: I've already tried this but it takes the element as a single character of the entire string. Data is not treated as a variable because of .text method in requests module.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is actually JSON. You can convert this string to a Python object and do whatever you want with it afterwards:

```
import json

data = '{"data":["Action & Adventure","Anime Features","Children & Family Movies","Classic Movies","Cult Movies","Documentaries","Dramas","Faith & Spirituality","Horror Movies","Independent Movies","International Movies","LGBTQ Movies","Movies","Music & Musicals","Romantic Movies","Sci-Fi & Fantasy","Sports Movies","Stand-Up Comedy","Thrillers"]}'

genres = json.loads(data)['data']
# ['Action & Adventure', 'Anime Features', 'Children & Family Movies', ...]
```

Print it one by line:

```
print('\n'.join(genres))
```

Or if you want an hyphen:

```
print('\n'.join([f'-{genre}' for genre in genres]))
```

Output:

```
-Action & Adventure
-Anime Features
-Children & Family Movies
-Classic Movies
...
```

You can directly use `requests` to manipulate the JSON for you:

```
import requests

url = "https://netflix-unofficial.p.rapidapi.com/api/genres"

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "netflix-unofficial.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': //here goes my private key
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

data = response.json()
genres = data['data']
```

Comment: Great, it worked! I previously tested using ast and eval() but with no results.

Comment: Also, about `eval`, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice